# How can I find out which USB Type C port is supplying power

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, power

I have a MacBook Pro 15" Late 2016 with USB-C ports. I also have a LG 27UD88 monitor that can supply 60W, and a CallDigit Dock that can supply 90 W. But still sometimes the MacBook is at 0% battery, even when working with very low CPU load.

**Question:** Is there a way to find out from which port the MacBook is supplied with power?

Of course, I could measure the current on the AC side of the power supply, but I'd rather look for a software tool.

Comment: Does System Information > Hardware > Power not give you the info you're looking for? My computer shows the wattage of my charger (60W), but I'm on a Magsafe based laptop, not USB-C.

Answer (score 2):

The current should be displayed in your Power settings menu.

[image]

Comment: This is true for Apple power supplies, but not for 3rd party ones. Also, not alle connected supplies are not shown. But thanks, better than nothing